# How to use open graph metatag with next js 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, meta-tags

In the recent update of Next JS 13 they introduced a new way to handle meta tags which was a different way as the traditional method by creating Next Head and writing the usual html meta tag. in the new method we create a metadata object like way. but i haven't found a way to use open graph metadata.

```
export const metadata = {
  title:
    " this is the title of the web",
  description:
    " this is the description section",
  ogtitle: "this is open graph title for testing", // i thought this could be the case 
};
```

so how can i use open graph in the metadata?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ther’s a section of the `metadata` object dedicated to OpenGraph’s metadata.

Please refer to the [relevant documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#opengraph) for more details.

The short version is this:

```js
export const metadata = {
  openGraph: {
    title: 'this is open graph title for testing',
    description: 'Some description',
  }
};
```

Also I expect you to need to generate such data dynamically, based on the path, search parameters and queries. If so use `export async function generateMetadata(…)` instead of `export const metadata`. The [relevant documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#generatemetadata-function) helps a lot.

Comment: yes i have the dynamic genetrateMetadata. this is for the general section.